# How to create an array of input field values and labels in React and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I would like to create an array like this one from my input fields where the value is the value user inputs to the field and label is the label text. React/TypeScript used.

```
  const foods = [
    {
      value: 6,
      label: 'Amount of apples',
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: 'Amount of bananas',
    }
  ]
```

I have set the states here:

```
  let [field1, setField1] = useState<number>(0);
  let [field2, setField2] = useState<number>(0);
```

Here are the two input fields with labels and a button at the end. When the form is submitted, the new array should get created from the input fields.

```
  return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

          <label>Amount of apples
            <input
              placeholder="Add apples"
              type="number"
              value={field1}
              onChange={(e) => setField1(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}
            />
          </label>

          <label>Amount of bananas
            <input
              placeholder="Add bananas"
              type="number"
              value={field2}
              onChange={(e) => setField2(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}
            />
          </label>

        <button type="submit">Count</button>
        </form>   

  )
```

Can someone help me to form the array of labels and input values?

I've tried a lot of things, but I'm failing to get data from the input values and labels and don't know how to create an array so that I can use it later in another function like this:

```
foods.map(food => food.label)
```

Should I save the array to a new state?

Comment: Are you just trying to create the `foods` array out of the two state variables `field1` and `field2`?

Comment: I added some more text to my question explaining what I need to do with the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support an arbitrary number of different fruits, you can change your state to an object instead of a bunch of individual numbers. You can then create a function that builds the array. Here is some example code:

```js
import React from 'react';

const inputs = ['apples', 'bananas'];

export const MyComponent = () => {
    const [fruitAmounts, setFruitAmounts] = React.useState<
        Record<string, number>
    >(
        Object.fromEntries(
            inputs.map((fruit) => {
                return [fruit, 0];
            }),
        ),
    );


    const getFruitsArray = () => {
        return Object.entries(fruitAmounts).map((entry) => {
            return {
                label: `Amount of ${entry[0]}`,
                value: entry[1],
            };
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            {inputs.map((fruit) => {
                return (
                    <label key={fruit}>
                        {`Amount of ${fruit}`}
                        <input
                            placeholder={`Add ${fruit}`}
                            type='number'
                            value={fruitAmounts[fruit]}
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                setFruitAmounts({
                                    [fruit]: parseInt(event.target.value, 10),
                                    ...fruitAmounts,
                                });
                            }}
                        />
                    </label>
                );
            })}

            <button type='button'>Count</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

You can call `getFruitsArray()` anywhere in your component.

Comment: I have to later access the array in a different function before the return like this: foods.map(food => food.label). So is it possible to access this array like that? The array foods is not found when I try to console.log it anywhere else.

Comment: Got it to work now when I just created the array before the return.

Comment: But is there a way to get the labels from code so that you don't have to hard code them to the array again?

Comment: I edited my answer, but I'm a bit unclear on what you want to do. If you are looking to create multiple inputs that all function in similar ways, you could make a `FoodInput` component. You could have an array of these components and each one could have a `label` prop.

Comment: Alright I think I figured out what you're trying to do, and I updated my example accordingly. Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some value in the array as:

```
const foods = [
  {
   value: 6,
   label: 'Amount of apples',
   name: 'Apple',
  },
  {
   value: 2,
   label: 'Amount of bananas',
   name: 'Banana',
  },
];
```

then state as:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(foods)
```

then return as:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {foods.map((food) => {
    return (
      <div key={food.name}>
        <label >{food.label}</label>
        <input
          name={food.name}
          type='number'
          value={food.value}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
  )}
  <button type="submit" >Count</button>
</form>
```

add handleInputChange function:

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  const modifiedFood = foods.map((i) => {
    if (i.name === name) {
      i.value = Number(value);
    }
    return i
  })
  setCount(pre => pre = modifiedFood)
};
```

add handleSubmit function:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(count);
};
```